# Tools for investigating hydrogen bonding

Tags: physical-chemistry, hydrogen-bond

What would be the best tool to investigate local molecular organization in liquid mixtures due to hydrogen bonding?

For example, I might want to look at how water molecules hydrogen bond to [PNIPAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly(N-isopropylacrylamide)#Chemical_and_Physical_Properties) vs with itself.

Qualitative analysis would be good (does one type of site preferentially hydrogen bond with a specific other site) but quantitative would be even better (enthalpy of h bonds and entropy  reduction due to local organization).

What is a good way to look into this?

Comment: What is PNIPAM?

Comment: Do you want a computational tool? It's a bit unclear when you say "qualitative analysis."

Comment: @ssavec I added a link to PNIPAM's wikipedia page which explains a bit about how it interacts with water. The short story though is that its a molecule that interrupts water's hydrogen bonding with itself.

Comment: I'd prefer a computational tool but I didn't want to restrict the answers if an experimental option is far superior.

Comment: The polymer is obviously very sensitive to the enthalpy/entropy balance. This would be very difficult to describe correctly using theory. You need MD simulations to have at least semi-qualitative approximation. Experimentally, THz spectroscopy is good for detecting the solvation. Check the Resolv cluster, which tries to study solvation by all possible means: http://www.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/solvation/